# Are the automorphisms of the power semigroup of a cancellative semigroup cardinality-preserving?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, automorphism-groups

Let $S$ be a semigroup (written multiplicatively) and $f$ be an automorphism of the power semigroup $\mathcal P(S)$ of $S$, that is, a bijective function on the family of all non-empty subsets of $S$ such that $f(XY) = f(X) f(Y)$ for all non-empty sets $X, Y \subseteq S$, where $XY := \{xy : x \in X, y \in Y\}$ and similarly with $f(X) f(Y)$.

> **True or False?** If $S$ is cancellative, then $|f(X)| = |X|$ for every non-empty $X \subseteq S$.

For a "True" answer, cancellativity is kind of necessary here. Indeed, let $S$ be a [left zero semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_semigroup) with $|S| \ge 2$ ("left zero" means that $xy = x$ for all $x, y \in S$). If $f$ is *any* bijection on $\mathcal P(S)$, then $f(XY) = f(X) f(Y)$ for all $X, Y \subseteq S$; and since $|S| \ge 2$, we can certainly define $f$ in such a way that $|f(S)| \ne |S|$ (pick $x \in S$ and let $f$ be the transposition of $\mathcal P(S)$ that swaps $\{x\}$ and $S$).